# php built-in server does not complain about same port being used on windows

Tags: php

```php
php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:8000 "path-to-project\server.php"
php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:8000 "path-to-project\server.php"
php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:8000 "path-to-project\server.php"
```

they'll all run successfully but only the first one will serve it when you close the first one, the second takes over and so on.

I want to run the `php built-in server` command programmatically multiple times and I need a way to know what port is being used so I can increment the port number.

I've tried `fsockopen()` which is something like this

```php
        $connection = @fsockopen('localhost', '8000');

        if (is_resource($connection)) {

            fclose($connection);

            echo 'this port is in use';
        }
```

The problem with this way is that it's not very fast and going to open and close a lot of socket connections.

I'm wondering what's the other way to handle this, or how to get all the in-use port from php built in server.

**Update**
For mac it complains about same port being used
so if I run this mutiplue times,
`passthru(php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:8000 "path-to-project\server.php", $status);`
I can check the `$status` to see whether it's used or not, for windows how to achieve this? I am still waiting for the answer, cheers.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? May be there is a better approach then running multiple servers.

Comment: @vuryss I want to run multiple servers programmatically, and I do not want to specify the port number every time I run the command. I will have a default port which will be `8000` and this will be the port for the first server, but after the first server, I want a way to increase the port by 1. so second time I run the command the port should be `8001` and so on. Hope this make sense to you, if not please me know.

Comment: I understood what you're trying to do. But I wanted to see why you want it that way. Which problem are you trying to solve with multiple php servers on subsequent ports? I haven't seen many use cases for having multiple php servers on a single host.

Comment: @vuryss oh, this is really for local dev easier, an example is when I working on one app, and for some reason, I need to check another app code. so I want to run two apps at the same time, I know that I can specify the port number, but I would like to omit it if I can.